# varchar Output value not returning from sql server in php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a php file which executes a sql server stored procedure and returns a OUTPUT value which is of VARCHAR datatype. If the output value is set to integer it is working fine. if the output value is set to varchar it returns empty value. below is my php code and sql server stored procedure. please help me where am wrong. Thank you

```
$retbillno = 'REF';

    $sp_name = "{call Stp_Bill(?,?)}";

    $params = array(   
                     array($massno,         SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
                     array($retbillno,      SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)
                   );  


    $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sp_name, $params);

    if( $stmt3 === false )  
    {  
         echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";  
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
         //die( print_r( "0", true));  
    }  

    else
    {   
        sqlsrv_next_result($stmt3);
        echo $retbillno;

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3);  
        sqlsrv_close( $conn);
    }
```

and stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Stp_Bill 
@massno INT,
@retbillno VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @retbillno='REF02455'
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: When you execute a procedure with some sort of output parameter, you need to declare the variable as output. That said, using an output parameter is probably unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: Please be clear with what you are saying. I dont get you clear

Comment: The variable needs to be declared output when executing the procedure. e.g. `declare @m int = 1; declare @r varchar(20); exec stp_bill @massno = @m, @retbillno = @r output;` but really you shouldn't need an output parameter because you can just capture a regular select statement in your php code. e.g. instead of having output, just change your procedure to simply be `select 'REF02455';`

Comment: i done that, but that does not work.. remember when the output value is in integer, it works perfect. it dont return value only when it is of varchar datatype. but i need a varchar value to be returned

Answer (score 0):

I have had to deal with similar issue with C# and SQL output parameter of datatype VARCHAR. What I found was that when declaring the parameter in C# I need to mention its size

```cs
// The below will not return any value larger than the length of existing value in someInitialValue
var myOutParam = new SqlParameter("@calculatedParam", someInitialValue);
myOutParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
con.ExecuteQuery(...);

// if for example myInitialValue was "A" and your returned "XYZ" from the procedure, your finalValue would only be "X"
var finalValue = myOutParam.Value;
```

Proper way to address this issue is to provide the parameter declaration with the expected size

```
// The below declaration will return properly
var myOutParam = new SqlParameter("@calculatedParam", someInitialValue);
myOutParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
myOutParam.Size=3;
con.ExecuteQuery(...);

// if for example myInitialValue was "A" and your returned "XYZ" from the procedure, your finalValue would only be "XYZ"
var finalValue = myOutParam.Value;
```

Translate this to your PHP requirements and it should address your issue.